# For Terraform's aws_eks_cluster, how can I use an existing VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

Terraform v1.2.8

I have a YAML configuration file that I've used to create an AWS EKS cluster via `eksctl` that uses an existing VPC, like this

```yaml
kind: ClusterConfig
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5

metadata:
  name: sandbox
  region: us-east-1
  version: "1.23"

# The VPC and subnets are for the data plane, where the pods will
# ultimately be deployed.
vpc:
  id: "vpc-123456"
  clusterEndpoints:
    privateAccess: true
    publicAccess: false
  subnets:
    private:
    ...
```

Then I do this to create the cluster

```
$ eksctl create cluster -f eks-sandbox.yaml
```

Now I want to use Terraform instead, so I looked at the [aws_eks_cluster](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eks_cluster) resource, and am doing this

```yaml
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "eks_cluster" {
  name     = var.cluster_name
  role_arn = var.iam_role_arn

  vpc_config {
    endpoint_private_access = true
    endpoint_public_access  = false
    security_group_ids      = var.sg_ids
    subnet_ids              = var.subnet_ids
  }
}
```

...but the resource doesn't allow me to specify an existing VPC? Hence when I do a

```
$ terraform plan -out out.o
```

I see

```
  # module.k8s_cluster.aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster will be created
  + resource "aws_eks_cluster" "eks_cluster" {
      + arn                   = (known after apply)
      + certificate_authority = (known after apply)
      + created_at            = (known after apply)
      + endpoint              = (known after apply)
      + id                    = (known after apply)
      + identity              = (known after apply)
      + name                  = "sandbox"
      + platform_version      = (known after apply)
      + role_arn              = "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/EKSClusterAdminRole"
      + status                = (known after apply)
      + tags_all              = (known after apply)
      + version               = (known after apply)

      + kubernetes_network_config {
          + ip_family         = (known after apply)
          + service_ipv4_cidr = (known after apply)
          + service_ipv6_cidr = (known after apply)
        }

      + vpc_config {
          + cluster_security_group_id = (known after apply)
          + endpoint_private_access   = true
          + endpoint_public_access    = false
          + public_access_cidrs       = (known after apply)
          + security_group_ids        = (known after apply)
          + subnet_ids                = [
              + "subnet-1234567890",
              + "subnet-2345678901",
              + "subnet-3456789012",
              + "subnet-4567890123",
              + "subnet-5678901234",
            ]
          + vpc_id                    = (known after apply)
        }
    }
```

See the `vpc_id` output? But I don't want it to create a VPC for me. I want to use an existing VPC, like in my YAML configuration file. Can do I use an existing VPC to create an AWS EKS cluster in Terraform? TIA

Comment: Have you tried adding the `vpc_id` argument inside of the `vpc_config` block?

Comment: If you are able to use `terraform-aws-eks` then this becomes significantly easier.

Comment: @MarkoE `vpc_id` is not a `vpc_config` argument, only an attribute, thanks!

Comment: @MattSchuchard, I'll look at `terraform-aws-eks`, thanks!

Comment: Hm, yeah, I wasn't really sure if that would work, the docs seemed fuzzy so I thought it was worth giving it a shot. :)

Comment: @MarkoE, yeah it just means you can use that value for output, e.g.,
`output "eks_cluster" {
  value = aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster.vpc_id
}`

Comment: Haha, yeah I know that, I somehow read it as "you can also use it as an argument" but obviously not. :)

Comment: @MarkoE, ok i didn't mean to be condescending.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, `terraform-aws-eks` worked like a champ, so if you'd put that as an answer, I'd accept it. However, looking at the output, it just seems to call `aws_eks_cluster.this` so it just seems to be using the `aws_eks_cluster` module also.

Comment: @ChrisF Yes it still uses the `aws_eks_cluster` resource in the module, but it also combines tons of other functionality in a module that has existed since EKS was in beta in May 2018, so it is super reliable and easy relative to "reinventing the wheel".

Comment: You specify `subnet_ids` in the VPC config. The VPC has to already exist for those subnets to exist. The resource can deduce the VPC ID from the subnet IDs. The `aws_eks_cluster` resource does not create a new VPC, it **only** works with existing VPCs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unfortunately resource `aws_eks_cluster` doesn't have argument `vpc_id`, but [has such attribute](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eks_cluster#:%7E:text=vpc_id%20%2D%20ID%20of%20the%20VPC%20associated%20with%20your%20cluster.). When you specify `subnet_ids` it will be created in subnet's VPC, that you specified.**